# How read data from a file to store data into two one dimensional lists?

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and cannot find this online.

Given a .txt file that contains:

```
Apple  : Red 
Orange : Orange 
Banana : Yellow
```

How can I get two lists like `[Apple, Orange, Banana]`, and `[Red, Orange, Yellow]`? 
I have seen some examples on the internet but the result is a two-dimensional list.

```
with open('fruit.txt') as f:
   List= [x.strip().split(':') for x in f.readlines()]
print List
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the split lines and then unpack them to two variables, like this

```
with open('fruit.txt') as f:
    fruits, colors = zip(*(line.strip().split(":") for line in f))

print fruits, colors
# ('Apple ', 'Orange', 'Banana') (' Red', ' Orange', ' Yellow')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fruit = []
color = []
with open('fruit.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fruit.append(line.split(':')[0].strip())
        color.append(line.split(':')[1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Import **csv** library where you can read the lines and delimit the words/fields in each line.
in your case it is `":"`

And append each word/field to the list you want using list method **`list.append()`**

```
import csv
a=[]
b=[]
with open('fruit.txt') as f:

         for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=":"):

              a.append(row[0])
              b.append(row[1])


 print a
 print b
```